# How to bind data without using web method

Tags: angularjs

I am not getting proper output please solve this it gives response also but I am not getting proper output.  data taken from server and bind that to drop down and click on button it give response this is my requirement I am a beginner please try to solve this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["Meth"] != null && Request.QueryString["Meth"].ToString() != "")
            {
                string Req = Request.QueryString["Meth"].ToString();
                if (Req == "GL")
                {
                    List<Names> lst = new List<Names>();
                    lst = GetList();
                    if (lst != null)
                    {
                        string m_Result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
                        Response.Write(m_Result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static List<Names> GetList()
    {
        List<Names> names = new List<Names>();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.42,1433;Initial Catalog=mycatalog;User ID=myid;Password=mypassword"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "select RoleName from HN_Master_User_Role";
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
        }
        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                names.Add(new Names(dr["RoleName"].ToString()));
        }
        return names;
    }
```

Angular Code :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCntrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.fillList = function () {
        $scope.RoleName = "";

        var httpreq = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'WebForm1.aspx?Meth=GL',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'dataType': 'json'
            },
            data: {}
        }

        $http(httpreq).success(function (response) {
            $scope.RolesList = response;

        })
    };

    $scope.fillList();

    $scope.click = function (selectedValue) {                                        
        alert(selectedValue);
    }
});
```

HTML Code :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
    user Roles: <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" ng-model="dropdown">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option data-ng-repeat="Role in RolesList">{{Role.RoleName}}</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" class="button" value="button" ng-click="click(dropdown)"  />
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to remove the IP and login details to the database...

Comment: its not working i already tried

Comment: Remove them from the question i mean, not the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want to do a simple `get`?

```
$http.get("WebForm1.aspx?Meth=GL")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.RolesList = response.data;
    });
```

Comment: where it can be written. i cannot understand

Comment: Instead of the $http you have in your angular code.

Comment: Are you debugging your code to see where it goes wrong? Both client-side and server.

Comment: its shows in response but not binding while in debug

Comment: i got a data in response but it is not visible in drop down

Comment: Can you show the data you got? There might be something wrong with your angular template (HTML). You should probably use `ng-options` on the `select` instead of `ng-repeat` on the `options` btw.

Comment: template is also good. i got data in drop down is empty data like  blank data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96323/discussion-between-arg0n-and-chaitanya).

Comment: $scope.RolesList = response.data; i got the data

Comment: Ah, the tricky `.data` in .NET :). Glad you figured it out. Debugging usually helps in these situations.